# remote interpreter pycharm - file not found

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm

I have a Python install and some Python files on a remote linux box which I want to be able to run/edit remotely from my local install of Pycharm.

I have set up the interpreter in Pycharm to point at my remote install via ssh. Everything connects okay.

However, if I try and run a remote file I get a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<c308890d-7a7a-4ff4-8ea8-ebdba2c99bea>/test.py' error.`

I can get around this error by going to Run -> Edit configurations -> Script path, and manually removing `<c308890d-7a7a-4ff4-8ea8-ebdba2c99bea>` and replacing with the correct remote path.

Is there anything I need to change in the set up such that Run will work automatically without having to manually amend the script path in Run configurations each time?

Comment: Can't you just run the same run configuration every time?

Comment: Can you do that for different .py files?

Comment: Not sure here, but, is the path the same for every one of those different scripts? Have you tried, in the configuration window, going to the template section and creating a template with the correct path in it?